# Change colorbar boundaries in geopandas plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I'm stuck on something that should be simple, but I couldn't find an answer. I'm trying to plot something, like this:

```
world['gdp_per_cap'] = world.gdp_md_est / world.pop_est

world.plot(column='gdp_md_est', legend = True)
```

Which brings this:

[image]

But I'd like to change the colorbar (and the color mapping) so it goes from 0 to 3e7. Tried to do it through `legend_kwds`, read about `vmin`, `vmax` and `plt.colorbar()`, but couldn't find a way to combine that knowledge into custom boundaries/limits for my colorbar. What am i missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add vmax/vmin in the plot. if you want to change the colormap, just pass the name to cmap.

```
world.plot(column='gdp_md_est', legend = True,vmin = 0.5e7,max=1.75e7,  cmap='Reds')
```

Comment: I suppose you have a typo - "vmax=1.75e7" will be correct